# c# xamarin.forms - Label in ListView loses value after OnPropertyChanged - only on Windows devices

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

**Project : https://github.com/KMikulcak/App1**

MyApp needs to refresh its content every few seconds - so I use a async method in the Main Thread, to get the Data from the DataSource and renew the values in the Page

The app runs on Android emulator as intended, but on Windows devices i have the problem that after the first refresh, the Label in the ListView loses its value.

**If you rotate or change the Page the Label ist visible again, until the next refresh**

so i try to guide you shortly through my code:

**Page**
**XAML**

```
<pages:BasePage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="Layout" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ItemListView" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:BasePage.Content>
```

**Page Code behind**

```
public TestPage()
    {
        ViewModel = new TestViewModel();
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        ItemListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemListCell));
        ItemListView.ItemsSource = ViewModel.ObservableItems;
        RunAction = Run;
    }
```

**ListView Costum Cell**

```
public class ItemListCell : ViewCell
{
    public ItemListCell()
    {
        var nameLabel = new Label
        {
            FontFamily = "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
            FontSize = 30,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            WidthRequest = 500,
            HeightRequest = 40,
            MinimumWidthRequest = 500,
            MinimumHeightRequest = 40
        };
        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

        var cellLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = {nameLabel}
        };

        View = cellLayout;
    }
}
```

So its pretty much basic stuff here, in the xaml i have a ListView and in the Code Behind i set the ItemsSource and the ItemTemplate

**Refresh process in the Page**

```
internal Action RunAction { get; set; }

private void StartRefresh()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            RunAction();
        });
    }

public async void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ViewModel.Refresh();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }

protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        StartRefresh();
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemListModel> ObservableItems { get; }
public async void Refresh()
    {
        var items = await DataSource.GetItemList();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var od = ObservableItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);
            if (od == null)
            {
                ObservableItems.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (od.Name != item.Name)
                {
                    od.Name = item.Name;
                    od.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**ItemModel**

```
public class ItemListModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected internal virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

So what basicly happens : when the Page gets initialized, it sets the **RunAction to Run()** and when the Page appears, it starts the StartRefresh() Method

Now the Run() Method runs in the MainThread  and every 5 seconds refreshes the ObservableList in the ViewModel

And overall I cant figure out why the Label in the ListView drops the value

I hope one of you guys can help

**Debug Output**

TestPage.Ctor

TestPage.OnAppearing

TestPage.RefreshStart

TestViewModel.Refreshing

TestViewModel.Refreshing

ItemListModel.OnPropertyChanged:Id[2], Name

The Thread 0x2218 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The Thread 0x1984 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

TestViewModel.Refreshing

.

.

.

edit. is there maybe a windows specific render method or a costum controll / method for those cases ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On Windows, have you debugged step by step, particularly the Refresh method? Just to see if the method is called and works as expected.

Comment: yes, i added also Debug.WriteLine() on every important call (as for example in propertychanged) and its doing exactly what it should be, i checked the Label itself, by giving it a background color, even a frame to check the size and if the whole label drops or just the text

Comment: Any reason your ObservableCollection is read-only, i.e., only has getter? Try adding a setter if it does not break your logic. Moreover, I've just read this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18631/listview-binding-to-observablecollection-does-not-update-gui, maybe it's a layout problem. Try rotating your phone/window/emulator to see if the GUI is updated.

Comment: yes if you rotate or change the Page, it is for those 5 seconds back again, then dissappears again

Comment: setter on observable doesnt change something, and the referenced link (put a grid arround the listview) also doesnt work for me - but thanks !